# ¿Cómo actualizar un registro de la DB con Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, rest

Tengo una función que pretende actualizar un valor de una tabla de la base de datos, donde recibo la data (nombre, correo, telefono) y quiero actualizar un registro con algún ID. Ejemplo:

Suponiendo que tengo el siguiente registro:

```
id nombre correo       telefono
4  Obama  obama@eu.gob 77889900
```

Y quiero actualizar ese registro para cambiar la información de sus campos:

```
id nombre correo       telefono
4  Obam   obama@eu.com 44889900
```

Este es el código que tengo, la variable `$id` la obtengo como argumento de mi función `editar_usuario_post( $id )`.

```
$this->db->reset_query();
$datos = array(
  'id' => $id,
  'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
  'correo' => $data['correo'],
  'telefono' => $data['telefono']
);
$this->db->insert('usuarios', $datos);
```

Answer (score 0):

Para actualizar un registro en tu modelo deberia de quedar de la siguiente manera:

```
public function editar_usuario_post($id, $datos){
    //Se hace el where para actualizar el registro que se desea
    $this->db->where('id', $id);
    //Se hace el update a la tabla con los datos enviados
    $this->db->update('usuarios', $datos);
}
```

Tu controler quedaría así:

```
//Arreglo con los datos a actualizar
$datos = array(
    'nombre' => $data['nombre'],
    'correo' => $data['correo'],
    'telefono' => $data['telefono']
);
//Se pasan los parámetros hacia el controlador
$this->model->editar_usuario_post($id, $datos);
```